# Emacs - Отсутствует нумерация для пустых строк

Tags: emacs, manjaro

Пытаюсь настроить нумерацию строк в Emacs. Когда открываю два буфера, пропадает нумерация у пустых строк.

[image: Пример]

Использую Manjaro Linux, Emacs открываю в терминале.

Код из файла .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))

(unless window-system
  (add-hook 'linum-before-numbering-hook
    (lambda ()
      (setq-local linum-format-fmt
          (let ((w (length (number-to-string
                (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))
            (concat "%"(number-to-string w) "d"))))))

(defun linum-format-func (line)
  (concat
   (propertize (format linum-format-fmt line) 'face 'linum)
   (propertize " " 'face 'mode-line)))

(unless window-system
  (setq linum-format 'linum-format-func))
```